# Installation of android ndk

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded the latest ndk from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing. For installing the ndk i used the following command in the terminal.

`chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin` returned `` chmod: cannot access `android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin': No such file or directory ``

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `7-zip` to extract the ndk .bin file.
To install 7-zip type the following into the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

and extract with the command:

```
7za x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin
```

It will extract to the current directory with the same name

Comment: @gman: Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/645448/revisions) and also edit the spelling and grammar for your edits in the future? **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Run `chmod +x /path/to/android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin` and make sure you haven't removed the file meanwhile accidentally.